# Count the program-steps

Tags: performance, excel, vba, loops, lag

I have a "large" vba-programm with many loops, now I want to count each step respective command of my programm makes when i start it, so maybe I can find loops wich are not realy performant. I wanna have a number of executed steps.

Now anybody knows how that works? Or is in Excel2010 allready exist some functions for that?

Thx. I know my Enlgish is not very good. >.<

Edit 06.14.13
Now i write it so in my module

```
Sub DoStuff()
Dim sw As New Stopwatch
sw.Start
Call pranlesen.plan_gen
sw.Pause
Debug.Print "SomeFunction took " & format(sw.Elapsed * 1000, "0.000000") & " milliseconds"
End Sub
```

The class is right called as Stopwatch i don't know what's the defect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean "count the number of processor instructions", no there is no way to do that. However, you can measure elapsed time very accurately. See my article [**Accurate Performance Timers in VBA**](http://bytecomb.com/accurate-performance-timers-in-vba/) for a detailed description of using the Windows API function [**QueryPerformanceCounter**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644904.aspx) to construct a super-accurate stopwatch in VBA. Here's the full code for the Stopwatch class:

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Declare Function QueryPerformanceCounter Lib "kernel32" ( _
    lpPerformanceCount As UINT64) As Long
Private Declare Function QueryPerformanceFrequency Lib "kernel32" ( _
    lpFrequency As UINT64) As Long

Private pFrequency As Double
Private pStartTS As UINT64
Private pEndTS As UINT64
Private pElapsed As Double
Private pRunning As Boolean

Private Type UINT64
    LowPart As Long
    HighPart As Long
End Type

Private Const BSHIFT_32 = 4294967296# ' 2 ^ 32

Private Function U64Dbl(U64 As UINT64) As Double
    Dim lDbl As Double, hDbl As Double
    lDbl = U64.LowPart
    hDbl = U64.HighPart
    If lDbl < 0 Then lDbl = lDbl + BSHIFT_32
    If hDbl < 0 Then hDbl = hDbl + BSHIFT_32
    U64Dbl = lDbl + BSHIFT_32 * hDbl
End Function

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Dim PerfFrequency As UINT64
    QueryPerformanceFrequency PerfFrequency
    pFrequency = U64Dbl(PerfFrequency)
End Sub

Public Property Get Elapsed() As Double
    If pRunning Then
        Dim pNow As UINT64
        QueryPerformanceCounter pNow
        Elapsed = pElapsed + (U64Dbl(pNow) - U64Dbl(pStartTS)) / pFrequency
    Else
        Elapsed = pElapsed
    End If
End Property

Public Sub Start()
    If Not pRunning Then
        QueryPerformanceCounter pStartTS
        pRunning = True
    End If
End Sub

Public Sub Pause()
    If pRunning Then
        QueryPerformanceCounter pEndTS
        pRunning = False
        pElapsed = pElapsed + (U64Dbl(pEndTS) - U64Dbl(pStartTS)) / pFrequency
    End If
End Sub

Public Sub Reset()
    pElapsed = 0
    pRunning = False
End Sub

Public Sub Restart()
    pElapsed = 0
    QueryPerformanceCounter pStartTS
    pRunning = True
End Sub

Public Property Get Running() As Boolean
   Running = pRunning
End Property
```

Paste the above code in a new Class module and name the module "Stopwatch". Then anywhere else in your code you can do something like this:

```
Sub DoStuff
    Dim sw As New Stopwatch
    sw.Start
    myResult = SomeFunction(A, B, C)
    sw.Pause
    Debug.Print "SomeFunction took " & Format(sw.Elapsed * 1000, "0.000000") & " milliseconds"
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it might be useful, but i don't understand, what's SomeFunction does...?

Comment: Should i write there my mainfunction?

Comment: @Synoon "SomeFunction" is nothing. It means "put whatever you want here".

Comment: Yeah Yeah that's clear but should i put my main there and than start the marco over DoStuff